# C# maskedTextbox, how to disable whitespaces?

Tags: c#, removing-whitespace, maskedtextbox

I cant figure out how to disable whitespaces, I tried multiple things, and yes my mask is 00000000000 but still it allows whitespaces. Anyone know a fix?

Not much code to show, only:

Should only allow numbers to be entered, not whitespaces too :/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the KeyDown Event to your textbox and then add the following Code in the created method:

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
  {
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: this isnt textbox, its maskedtextbox, so this doesnt work :(

Comment: So there is no KeyDown Event for a masked Textbox?

Comment: @Rin there is a keydown event. Just go to your masked textbox --> Look to the properties page --> on the top right there is a little ligthning --> Click--> search for KeyDown --> double click in the empty space --> this should automaticly create the keydown event then copy my code and change "textbox" to the name of your masked textbox

Comment: @Rin look at this Video and just do that with your masked textbox and with the Key down Event https://youtu.be/P7deKDexgao

Comment: Thanks for help everyone, I finally figured it out and it works!

Comment: Btw, is there a textchanged event for masked textboxs?

Comment: @Rin yes there is, Look at the official msdn Site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Adding it is the Same way like the KeyDown Event

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. It definitely works