# Prohibit whitespaces in C# textBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a **Windows Forms** application and want to prohibit the user from entering *spaces* and other *whitespaces* into the `TextBox`. I do not want to check it after sending the form with a message appearing "You entered a space" or something like that. I do not want to use this:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
```

Because I would have to compare the key that was pressed with *all possible whitespaces*. 
Is there any way to set the `TextBox` to accept only characters which are *not whitespaces*?

Comment: You could use char.IsWhiteSpace when handling the OnKeyDown event.

Comment: @MassimoDiSaggio and how would I get the key value from the "e" argument so that it can be compared to char?

Comment: you can use regex as well with OnKeyDown or OnKeyPress event.,

Comment: Cast the KeyCode property to char.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# maskedTextbox, how to disable whitespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423674/c-sharp-maskedtextbox-how-to-disable-whitespaces)

Comment: @Clint I do not think so, since I am asking about textBox, and the other question is maskedTextBox and the answer only handles spaces, not all whitespaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dragons (whitespaces) can penetrate in your pond (`Textbox`) by *two* ways:

1. By pressing space
2. By changing `Text` (e.g. with a help of copy + paste).

So we have to close both breaches (*WinForms* code):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

private void MyTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  // we don't accept whitespace characters
  if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar)) 
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // We remove whitespaces from text inserted 
  (sender as TextBox).Text = Regex.Replace((sender as TextBox).Text, @"\s+", "");
}
```

In case you don't want to use *regular expression*, try *Linq*:

```
(sender as TextBox).Text = string.Concat((sender as TextBox)
  .Text
  .Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of simple and elegant solution I was looking for.

Comment: It could be spiced with something like: `var txt = sender as TextBox; int selStart = txt.SelectionStart; (...) txt.SelectionStart = selStart > txt.TextLength ? txt.TextLength : selStart;`. So, if you enter a space in the middle of the text, you just see the caret move forward and if the position is `TextLength` nothing happens. Otherwise the caret position is reset each time.

Answer (score -1):

Use Regex on KeyPress or KeyDown event like below,

```
if (!Regex.Match(TextBox.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]+$").Success)  
{  
    // first name was incorrect  
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid first name", "Message", 
    MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);  
    TextBox.Focus();  
    return;  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't prohibit entering whitespaces, only checks if they were entered and shows a message. This is exactly what i DO NOT WANT to have as it is written in the question.